# Cross between a crossword and sudoku. What's it called?

Tags: crosswords, puzzle-identification

My wife is a big fan of crosswords. Years ago I ran across a book with an unusual puzzle that was basically a crossword mixed with sodoku.

The center of the puzzle was an empty grid, perhaps 6x6, with a few letters filled in. Around the outside of the grid were the beginnings and endings of words. The page looked like a nearly empty grid with letters to the left and right, above and below it. There were no clues given.

Based just on the letters surrounding the grid an the few letters in the grid she had to figure out all the horizontal and vertical words.

She really liked that book but I have never been able to find another book like it. Anybody know what that kind of puzzle is called or who makes it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the [gryptic](https://crosswordfiend.com/2010/09/16/introducing-gryptics/)!

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. I knew asking on a stack exchange site would get me my answer. I spent a bunch of time searching and just couldn't come up with the right words to track it down. I spent an hour or more last night searching on Amazon for a book of them but without knowing the name it was hopeless. Thank you!

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find it. It appears in a quick search that there was only one book and it's not in stock on Amazon, I wonder if it's out of print. Also makes me wonder if it's likely the same book I bought my wife years ago. Hopefully I can find another source for them. Apparently there is an iOS app but my wife doesn't have iOS device.